# Idempotents: $e$ a primitive and $f$ an arbitrary idempotent, then $\dim eA\mid\dim\ fA$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a simple $k$-algebra, $e\in A$ be a primitive and $f\in A$ a not necessarily primitive idempotent. A text I am currently trying to understand seems to implicitly assume that $\dim eA$ divides $\dim fA$, which does not seem obvious to me.

Clearly, we may assume w.l.o.g. that $e$ is a summand of $f$ (since we may consider $1-f$ instead of $f$ otherwise). But how do we continue from here?

**Edit:** I should have mentioned that my rings are assumed to be unital and associative, and, if necessary, Artinian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you mean $A$ is associative and unital, and artinian, if that last point is not something you want it could be more.   Hence, 
for every $e\in A$, $eA$ is a (right) $A$-module because it is right ideal.  Since $A$ is simple, its modules are semisimple, i.e. products of simples.  Now $e$ is primitive so $eA$ is simple.  Associative algebras have one simple module up to isomorphism.  So $fA$ is a product of modules isomorphic to $eA$. 
 Hence, $\dim fA=m\cdot \dim eA$.

Comment: “Associative algebras have one simple module up to isomorphism”: This is the key fact I was not aware of. I presume you also require simplicity of $A$; then this is shown e.g. in [Lam: A First Course in Noncommutative Rings](https://books.google.de/books?id=2T5DAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR7&ots=PWrwaqJCfT&dq=lam%20noncommutative%20rings&lr&hl=de&pg=PA31#v=onepage&q=lam%20noncommutative%20rings&f=false), Thm. 3.3, p. 33.

Comment: “Now $e$ is primitive so $eA$ is simple”: Primitiveness of $e$ afaik only implies that $eA$ is indecomposable. Why is it simple?

Comment: The modules of $A$ are semisimple, i.e. they decompose into products of simples.  So indecomposable=simple.